# Ember Simple Auth Authorization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, authorization, ember-simple-auth

I am using Ember Simple Auth outh2 for my App. It works fine but i found an issue when open page in New Tab, when i open in new tab it is losing its authorization capabilities
Eg, If an user able to edit data on Login, When i open new tab he lost the privilege but user session is maintains.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin,
  authenticator: 'simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant'
  beforeModel: ->
    @get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant', {})
```

At Rails side added session variables like this

```
if session[:user].present?
  session[:user][:level] = cas_status["level"]
  session[:user][:super_user] = cas_status["super_user"]
end
```

Entire session works fine in single page application. And i don't find any custom configurations for ember.

Comment: Is your browser running in incognito mode?

Comment: No, it is not in incognito mode

Comment: Sorry I saw now that the session is maintained, however storing privileges in the session sounds like a pretty bad idea security-wise- you should avoid storing more than a user id in the session.

Comment: It has to access through out my application, Where can i store apart from session after login?

Comment: In your database. I usually use [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/cancancommunity/cancancan) for this.

Comment: If you want to know why you should not store in the session see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking

Comment: Can you show, how you access the data from within you ember app?